# Revision Hashing WebWorker Script

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-usemin

I'm using [rev-hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rev-hash) to prevent issues with the browser loading outdated files from its cache. It does this by appending a hash of the file's contents to the filename. I use [gulp-usemin](https://github.com/zont/gulp-usemin) to update my html with the modified filenames.

The problem is that my [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) scripts are referenced from javascript, so usemin doesn't replace it.

```
var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
```

Also, scripts imported inside `worker.js` are not updated.

```
importScripts('foo.js', 'bar.js');
```

Can someone suggest a clean mechanism for updating these? Right now I'm just updating them manually before each release.